# OpenGL Equivalent to DirectX's HWND override

Tags: opengl, directx

My desire is to simulate DirectX's `hDestWindowOverride` parameter from the `Direct3DDevice::Present()` call in OpenGL.

Or said in another way, is there a more elegant solution to quickly switching window without having to do `GetDC()`, `SetPixelFormat()`, `wglMakeCurrent()` render everything, then revert?

The intent is to make a general emulation layer, and re-structuring the code so this parameter isn't needed would not help solve the issue.

Comment: Well, technically it is invalid to change the pixel format of a window's device context once it has been set, so I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the pixel format of a window's device context once it has been set, so no worries there :P.

Comment: Okay, I was confused by your "then revert" statement. I think I see what you are trying to do now, you mean revert the device context that the current render context draws into?

Comment: Yeah.  So is the only solution switching using `wglMakeCurrent()` and going back, or is there a nice DirectX hack similarly?  I'm also wondering if using `wglMakeCurrent()` after everything has been drawn might have issues with `SwapBuffers()`.

Comment: `wglMakeCurrent ()` is the only way to do this. And I think you may very well have a point about `SwapBuffers ()` since WGL provides no mechanism for defining the actual number of back buffers. Most display drivers have an option under OpenGL-specific settings to enable triple-buffering since the WGL API lacks such language.

Comment: I would suggest looking into wined3d, but the only problem is it is layered on top of GLX and this discussion is about WGL :-\ Nevertheless, https://github.com/mirrors/wine/blob/master/dlls/wined3d/swapchain.c _may_ provide some insight. FBOs are one possible work-around.

Comment: Yeah, I took a read at their implementation shortly after I posted this and realized that it's a bit more extensive than I had hoped.  I think I'll just stick to disabling that functionality.